# Doing an Update in SQL, with a CASE WHEN Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

What I want to know, is it somehow possible to do an update to a table, in a Case statement? Or if there is Some way to do this? I have a button to pull a report (this button goes and calls a stored procedure, and it gets a list of columns and their residing columns).

I basically want to update the table, IF, and only IF, the `DateClosed` column is NULL AND `ClosedBy` is null (i.e., the end date was reached, so the campaign is CLOSED).

The way I usually determine if the campaign is closed, is by doing Checks on the start and end date. Ie When EndDate < GetDate() Then "Closed". So obviously that displays correctly, but my database displays null because there was no update.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CampaignStats]
    @from DATETIME,
    @to DATETIME
AS
    SELECT 
        CampaignName AS 'CAMPAIGN NAME',
        CampaignDescription AS 'CAMPAIGN DESCRIPTION',
        CASE
           WHEN EndDate >= GETDATE() AND StartDate <= GETDATE() THEN 'Active' 
           WHEN StartDate >= GETDATE() THEN 'Pending'
           WHEN CampaignStatus = 4 THEN 'Archived'
           ELSE 'Closed'
        END as 'CurrentStatus',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), StartDate, 106) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), EndDate, 106) AS 'CAMPAIGN DATES',
        Discount AS 'DISCOUNT',
        [Target] AS 'TARGET',
        Uptake AS 'UPTAKE',
        tc.DateAdded as 'DATE ADDED',
        U.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName As 'ADDED BY',
        CASE 
           WHEN CloseBy IS NULL AND EndDate < GETDATE() AND CloseBy = Null THEN 'System'
           WHEN CampaignStatus = 4 THEN 'Archived'
           WHEN CloseBy IS not Null THEN UU.FirstName + ' ' +  uu.LastName
           ELSE 'Not Closed'
        END AS 'CLOSED BY',
        DateClosed AS 'DATE CLOSED'
    FROM 
        Tbl_Campaign tc
    LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_User U ON Tc.AddedBy = U.UserId 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Tbl_User UU ON TC.CloseBy = UU.UserId
    WHERE 
       (startDate >= @from OR enddate <= @to)
       AND CampaignStatus IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that returns a single, atomic value - it is not used for "flow control" or executing code blocks or anything like that.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how i could do what im trying to do? Im suffering.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear - you have a *button to pull a report* - and in the next sentence you want to update a table? Can you post the table structure in question, and explains more clearly (possibly with showing some code) what you're trying to do??

Comment: @marc_s I have updated my question. I Want to either update my tbl_Campaign from within this stored procedure, or maybe use another but still call it from the same button?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also, in your second `CASE`, in the first `WHEN` clause, you have a `CloseBy = NULL` - you cannot compare a value to `NULL` using the usual equality operator - you need to check `CloseBy IS NULL`

Comment: Bless you kind sir. I will remember this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to update your table *before* the `SELECT` happens?

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Tbl_Campaign
SET  -- what do you want to update to what value here????
WHERE 
    DateClosed IS NULL
    AND ClosedBy IS NULL
```

Or what exactly are you trying to do?? You're still being rather unclear and vague in your question - you're not mentioning **WHAT** column in **WHICH** table you want to update to **WHAT** value if that condition is met.....

Comment: Okay the think is, the user will pull a report. SINCE Dateclosed doesnt always update, because i use LINQ statements to display the information, i often dont use the DATE CLOSED field. (Which was likely a mistake, but im  too deep now). So when they pull this report, IF the Date closed field is null, THEN just update the DB and make update to GetDate(). So UPDATE dbo.Tbl_Campaign
SET   DateClosed = GetDate()
    
WHERE DateClosed IS NULL AND ClosedBy IS NULL. Sorry im not the best at describing.

Comment: Non the less, you have helped me solve my problem :) I just had to put the Update statement before the select. I just couldnt figure out HOW to call the update, within the select statement. Obviously this was wrong as it had to be before.

Answer (score 0):

SQL only allows one operation per statement. SELECTs only read data, UPDATEs only write data.

If I've understood your problem though, you've got a NULL in an end date field that's preventing you from displaying your button correctly? If that's the case, you could do something like

```
SELECT
    StatusDate = 
        CASE WHEN EndDate < GETDATE() THEN 'Closed'
            WHEN EndDate > GETDATE() THEN 'Open'
            WHEN EndDate IS NULL THEN 'End Date not set'
        END
FROM
    SourceTable
```

Or, if it was easier in your code, wrap the CASE in an ISNULL or COALESCE function that can be used to fill in the default value.

None of these will update the table on the read, but they'll all stop the NULL from preventing your read returning anything at all.

Seeing your actual code now, what you want is something like this -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CampaignStats]
    @from DATETIME,
    @to DATETIME
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Make sure any NULLs we need to have been cleaned up
    UPDATE Tbl_Campaign
    SET    <Fields>
    WHERE  DateClosed IS NULL AND ClosedBy IS NULL
           AND (startDate >= @from OR enddate <= @to)
           AND CampaignStatus IN (1, 2, 3, 4);

    --Now return the data
    SELECT 
        CampaignName AS 'CAMPAIGN NAME',
        CampaignDescription AS 'CAMPAIGN DESCRIPTION',
        CASE
           WHEN EndDate >= GETDATE() AND StartDate <= GETDATE() THEN 'Active' 
           WHEN StartDate >= GETDATE() THEN 'Pending'
           WHEN CampaignStatus = 4 THEN 'Archived'
           ELSE 'Closed'
        END as 'CurrentStatus',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), StartDate, 106) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), EndDate, 106) AS 'CAMPAIGN DATES',
        Discount AS 'DISCOUNT',
        [Target] AS 'TARGET',
        Uptake AS 'UPTAKE',
        tc.DateAdded as 'DATE ADDED',
        U.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName As 'ADDED BY',
        CASE 
           WHEN CloseBy IS NULL AND EndDate < GETDATE() AND CloseBy = Null THEN 'System'
           WHEN CampaignStatus = 4 THEN 'Archived'
           WHEN CloseBy IS not Null THEN UU.FirstName + ' ' +  uu.LastName
           ELSE 'Not Closed'
        END AS 'CLOSED BY',
        DateClosed AS 'DATE CLOSED'
    FROM 
        Tbl_Campaign tc
    LEFT JOIN 
        tbl_User U ON Tc.AddedBy = U.UserId 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Tbl_User UU ON TC.CloseBy = UU.UserId
    WHERE 
       (startDate >= @from OR enddate <= @to)
       AND CampaignStatus IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: hey sorry i was very vague with my question. I Have edited it.

Comment: OK, final example edited to match your question. Hope it helps :-)